# PayPal /v1/invoicing/invoices/ REST API not available

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using the node.js SDK to create and send invoices on **sandbox**. The first 8-15ish creations and 0-2 sends return this error:

```
The requested resource (/v1/invoicing/invoices/) is not available.
```

It's not the JSON being sent, as sometimes an invoice goes through and sometimes it doesn't. I'm wondering if this is a sandbox issue (API is rate-limited in some manner), or if there's some initialization I should be doing before hand?

Roughly, here's my code:

```
paypal.configure ...

program // Commander
  .parse(process.argv)
  .args.forEach(function (arg) {
    fs.createReadStream(arg).pipe(
      parse({ columns: true, delimiter: '\t' }, function (error, data) {
        data.forEach(function (row) {
          // create invoice from each row in data
          var invoice = ...

          invoice
            .setShipping()
            .then(
              function (invoice) {
                return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                  paypal.invoice.create(invoice, function (error, invoice) {
              if (null === error) {
                resolve(invoice);
              } else {
                reject(error);
              }
                  });
                });
              }
            )
            .then(
              function (invoice) {
                paypal.invoice.send( invoice.id, function (error, invoice) {
                });
              }
            );
              })
            })
          );
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up running this on PayPal live and didn't run in to the issue above. My best guess is it's some sort of limiting on Sandbox.